# Getting extra data while using append on Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 dives with some kind of form that I want to be display.
For some reason When I am using append I am getting more text that I didn't ask for.

Here is the html-

```
 <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                    <h3>טריקו קצר</h3>

                    <div  dir="rtl" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">בחר צבע:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                            <option value="standard">בחר</option>
                            <option value="לבן">לבן</option>
                            <option value="שחור">שחור</option>
                            <option value="כחול-ים">כחול-ים</option>
                            <option value="בורדו">בורדו</option>
                            <option value="ירוק">ירוק</option>
                            <option value="סגול כהה">סגול כהה</option>
                            <option value="אדום">אדום</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div dir="rtl" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-2" class="select">בחר מידה:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
                            <option  class="center-button"value="standard">בחר</option>
                            <option value="Small">S</option>
                            <option value="Medium">M</option>
                            <option value="Large">L</option>
                            <option value="EE">EE</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="slider" class="select">כמות:</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="500" data-highlight="true"  />
                            <div class="ui-block-a button-basket"><button data-theme="b" id="triko" class="basket">הוסף לסל</button></div>
                    </div>


                </div>

                                                     <!-- end   TRIKO -->

            <!-- ----------------------------------     GUFIOT    ---------------------------------------- -->

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                    <h3>גופיות קייציות</h3>

                    <div  dir="rtl" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-3" class="select">בחר צבע:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3">
                            <option value="standard">בחר</option>
                            <option value="לבן">לבן</option>
                            <option value="אפור אמריקאי">אפור אמריקאי</option>
                            <option value="שחור">שחור</option>
                            <option value="כחול-ים">כחול-ים</option>
                            <option value="בורדו">בורדו</option>
                            <option value="ירוק">ירוק</option>
                            <option value="סגול כהה">סגול כהה</option>
                            <option value="אדום">אדום</option>
                            <option value="כחול כהה">כחול כהה</option>
                            <option value="ירוק כהה">ירוק כהה</option>
                            <option value="טורקיז">טורקיז</option>
                            <option value="כתום">כתום</option>
                            <option value="צהוב">צהוב</option>
                            <option value="לילך">לילך</option>
                            <option value="חציל">חציל</option>
                            <option value="ורוד">ורוד</option>
                            <option value="תכלת">תכלת</option>
                            <option value="ירוק זית">ירוק זית</option>
                            <option value="אופוויט">אופוויט</option>
                            <option value="ורוד זועק">ורוד זועק</option>
                            <option value="חום">חום</option>
                            <option value="מג'ב / לוטר">מג"ב/לוטר</option>
                            <option value="צהוב בננה">צהוב בננה</option>
                            <option value="ירוק תפוח">ירוק תפוח</option>                        
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div dir="rtl" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-4" class="select">בחר מידה:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-4" id="select-choice-4">
                            <option  class="center-button"value="standard">בחר</option>
                            <option value="Small">S</option>
                            <option value="Medium">M</option>
                            <option value="Large">L</option>
                            <option value="EE">EE</option>                                      
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="slider" class="select">כמות:</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="500" data-highlight="true"  />
                            <div class="ui-block-a button-basket"><button data-theme="b" id="gufiot" class="basket">הוסף לסל</button></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

<div class="order">
                        <h3>פרטי ההזמנה</h3>
                        <p class="item_name"></p>
                    </div>

                                                 <!-- end   gofiot -->
```

Here is my JQ code-

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#slider').on('slidestop',function(){
        var changeVar = $('#slider').val();

        $(".ui-block-a").one('click',function(){
          $(".item_name").append("<h2>טריקו קצר</h2>" + "צבע:" + $("#select-choice-1").val() + ", כמות: " + changeVar + ", מידה: " + $("#select-choice-2").val() + "<br>")
          $("#select-choice-1").val("standard")
          $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh')
           $("#select-choice-2").val("standard")
          $('#select-choice-2').selectmenu('refresh')
          $("#slider").val(0).slider("refresh");
          //$( "#select-choice-1 option:selected" ).text("fffff");
        });
    });

        $('#slider1').on('slidestop',function(){
        var changeVar1 = $('#slider1').val();

        $("#gufiot").one('click',function(){
          $(".item_name").append("<h2>גופיות קייציות</h2>" + "צבע:" + $("#select-choice-3").val() + ", כמות: " + changeVar1 + ", מידה: " + $("#select-choice-4").val() + "<br>")
          $("#select-choice-3").val("standard")
          $('#select-choice-3').selectmenu('refresh')
           $("#select-choice-4").val("standard")
          $('#select-choice-4').selectmenu('refresh')
          $("#slider1").val(0).slider("refresh");
          //$( "#select-choice-1 option:selected" ).text("fffff");
        });
    });
```

If I use the first function and then use the second I am getting another line that I didn't ask for. So insted of getting -

```
טריקו קצר

צבע:אפור אמריקאי, כמות: 308, מידה: Small
גופיות קייציות

צבע:שחור, כמות: 318, מידה: Small
טריקו קצר
```

I am getting -

```
טריקו קצר

צבע:אפור אמריקאי, כמות: 308, מידה: Small
גופיות קייציות

צבע:שחור, כמות: 318, מידה: Small
טריקו קצר

צבע:standard, כמות: 308, מידה: standard .
```

If I use just 1 of the functions its all good...

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem!
It happand because ".ui-block-a" is located on the other form so I am getting 2 appends...